# Show related entities in FAST search results

Tags: bcs, fast-search, bdc, sharepoint-search, custom-bcs

I've successfully created a .net assembly BCS to crawl external data in my enviorment. The BCS include an AssociationNavigator to crawl related entities based on foreign key. When i perform a crawl and debug the BCS connector i see that the AssociationNavigator method is hit and it returns the list of related entities.
My question is how on earth i get back this data in core search result?

My understanding of related entities was that if i search for a term that is on the 'source' entity, the child entities should return in the search results as well.
Am i wrong? Is there any way to make these child entities appear?

Comment: Have you checked the crawled properties being generated/returned when crawling your BCS source? Might me a mapping of crawled properties to managed properties issue..and you can display them.

Comment: When the content is being crawled it calls the NavigatorAccessor method and crawl the child entities. I checked the crawled properties and the properties are there (because of the child entity being crawled regardless of the navigator). I mapped one of these to a managed property but when i try to get it back in the core search result it doesnt come back. If i search for text that is in the child entity directly - it comes back. I fear that FAST doesnt event support this concept of child entities :(

Comment: Then my guess is that it's not just FAST, but crawler related to BCS.